# Combining two commands on one line

Tags: shell, unix, sed, replace, cut

is there any way I can combine these two commands:

```
sed -i 's/test=.*$/test=NEXTCOMMAND/' filename.cfg

tail -1 file2.txt | cut -f 7-
```

into something like this:

```
sed -i 's/test=.*$/test=`tail -1 file2.txt | cut -f 7-/`' filename.cfg
```

without assigning

```
"tail -1 file2.txt | cut -f 7-"
```

to a variable. My question is, if I can wrap somehow mentioned command to be a correct one?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `"` quotes instead of `'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting everything inside a script and just run a script file to execute all commands at once.

Try it with a bash script and see what it happens:
http://www.linfo.org/create_shell_1.html
(For more information)

Comment: Yeah, I know, the script for that isn't a big problem but I would like to have it in one line and without any variables... If it isn't possible at all, thats okay.